# Boolean output blocking the whole process

Tags: java

Sorry to bother you all with this but I can't seem to find the issue here. Still learning so any input would be great.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AllAboutMe {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        Boolean married;
        int age, height;

        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What is your age?");
        age = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What is your height? ");
        height = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Are you married?");
        married = keyboard.nextBoolean();

        char aChar = name.charAt(0);

        System.out.println("Your name is " + name);
        System.out.println("your initial is " + aChar);
        System.out.println("Your marital status is " + married);
        System.out.println("Your height is " + height);
        System.out.println("Your age is " + age);
    }

}
```

Now major issue is that when I run this it won't work. I have looked for and all I see is that I need to test the boolean value. Is this true? Everything else works fine but the Boolean option does not let me output.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what your problem is? I don't understand it from your description.

Comment: I don't get any issues with this code. Able to run successfully on my system.

Comment: Are you making sure to type in `true` or `false` and not `yes` or `no`?

Comment: Boolean output does not block entire processes. Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It looks like he is typing `yes` and getting `java.util.InputMismatchException` - OP, can you confirm?

Comment: Vikingsteve you are right I was answering yes or no and java would stop running. Very true by using true or false it works now. Sorry all silly basic mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working so far.
The question "Are you married?" can only be answered with "true" or "false".

Comment: Thank you very much worked perfectly

Comment: In future, please review existing answers before posting - your answer came minutes after an almost identical other answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Scanner `nextBoolean()` method uses a boolean pattern like this to validate input:

```
private static final String BOOLEAN_PATTERN = "true|false";
```

So you need to enter `true` or `false` - yes or no won't be accepted.

This is a little counter-intuitive, since java Boolean class has a method named `parseBoolean()` which returns boolean `true` for any string matching "true" (case insensitively) and boolean `false` for anything else.

But the `Scanner` class, as you have found, behaves a little differently.

If you want to accept `yes`, `no`, or even `y`, `n` or the like, you should use `Scanner.nextString()` and process the logic yourself.

Answer (score 0):

when you reach to "Are you married?" then pass true or false, don't ans in yes or no